# How to display SQL Server default constraints in asp classic?

Tags: asp-classic, sql-server-2008-r2

```
SELECT 
    TableName = t.Name,
    ColumnName = c.Name,
    dc.Name,
    dc.definition 
FROM
    sys.tables t 
INNER JOIN 
    sys.default_constraints dc ON t.object_id = dc.parent_object_id 
INNER JOIN 
    sys.columns c ON dc.parent_object_id = c.object_id 
                  AND c.column_id = dc.parent_column_id 
ORDER BY 
    t.Name
```

Asp classic page cannot display - dc.definition. TableName, ColumnName, Name show up OK in the recordset, but not `<definition>`. Using VarType to test the value type is says: (1) no valid data.

Answer (score 0):

The definition field may be null, or 'definition' may be a keyword. Try adding some code to deflect those issues, i.e.:

```
SELECT 
  TableName = t.Name,
  ColumnName = c.Name,
  dc.Name,
  ISNULL(dc.definition,'') AS [definitionField]
```

Comment: Daryl, thanks but still the same issue. I intentionally made all columns to have valid (not null) default values. Also the query in SSMS is working as expected and the definition fields are showing the correct default values. Mind you they show in parenthesis. Single for the strings and double for numbers. Removing the parenthesis via Replace(Replace.. etc. still doesn't help.

Comment: Could the parentheses be the problem? As a test, I'd try concatenating some junk to that part of the select statement -- `'x' + ISNULL(dc.definition,'') + 'x' AS [definitionField] `

Comment: No change. I see both 'X'-es but not the [definitionField] in between. On another note, a default value can be GetDate() too. How that is supposed to show in a fiction query? I am beginning to think that those default values are for internal server use and not to be exported. But I tried to focus on a single one, which I know is a number and still the same. That's strange. How can I be the first one to have this issues. Not too many results on Google searches and on this site either. Thank you!

Comment: Weird that you see the 'X'es but not the data you're looking for, as if the data is being dropped out before it's sent. Only other thing I can think of trying offhand would be to wrap that in a CAST to try to rule out data-typing issues: `CAST(ISNULL(dc.definition,'') AS varchar(5000)) AS [definitionField] `